# Can't find VS2010 setting in custom fonts and colours for numerics in .sql files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, configuration

In Visual Studio 2010, does anyone know how to change the custom font colour for numeric characters in `.sql` files? Here is an example of the problem I have:

[image]

and

[image]

Black characters against my dark brown background aren't the easiest on the eye.

I've been through every single "Display Item" in the *Fonts and Colors* options have have failed to locate the setting that controls this colour.

Comment: I'm just checking my own local instance of VS2010 and, as far as I can tell, the setting for Environment->Fonts and Colors->Number controls the display colour used by numbers both in .sql and in .cs files. Is it set to black in your case?

Comment: @Malice - no mine is set to White, which works fine in .cs files but not .sql.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors. Look for "Identifier" under Text Editor. It hopefully will allow you to change the color.

[Link to what I found](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vssetup/thread/e93ab1bc-114a-45cb-a708-3dcd20911b00)

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I have been through every single "Display Item" in the list but there isn't a single setting that has this colour.

Comment: I apologize. Maybe try a color scheme already created and changing it or create your own through studiostyl.es/schemes